# How can i get the timezone value from a moment object?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a moment object like below

[image]

from which i want to extract the time zone value "PDT".
How can i get this value using moment?

i have tried

```
moment.tz(this.startDate.toString()).zoneAbbr();
```

but that returns a value "UTC"

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are seeing "PDT" as a consequence of the browser's built–in *Date.prototype.toString* method, it has nothing to do with moment.js. The time zone is entirely dependent on the host environment settings, and the format of the string is entirely browser dependent, some may not have the time zone at all, and others may represent it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I am Afraid you will get this only.. 
Since this is how the getZoneAbbr function works.

```
function getZoneAbbr () {
    return this._isUTC ? 'UTC' : '';
}
```

Now, This is a problem. UTC is what one can use with timeOffest to determine which TimeZone you are lying in. 
and only way to do it to make a list of Time zone names with their offset values, then compare which offset value you get. 
then you can pick your time zone.

Even the normal JavaScript Date function do not have this support as in yet. you will have to create that offset and time zone name map yourself.

Comment: Note that the timezone offset is entirely dependent on system settings, Date objects don't have an offset themselves. There are many time zones that have the same offset but a different name. There is no standard for naming time zones either, nor for their abbreviations. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You might wan't to add the specific timezone you're in for the date that you parse like following:

```
moment.tz(moment.now(), 'America/New_York').zoneAbbr();
```

Comment: Its returning "UTC" instead of "PDT"

Answer (score 0):

Moment had the `z` / `zz` [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) parameter to get abbreviated time zone name, **but** as the doc says:

> **Note:** as of **1.6.0**, the z/zz format tokens have been deprecated from plain moment objects. [Read more about it here.](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162) However, they *do* work if you are using a specific time zone with the moment-timezone addon.

In the linked github issue, [moment developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) [suggest](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162#issuecomment-182539707) to use [`moment.tz.guess()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) when creating moment object to have good chances of getting enviroment's timezone.

Here a working code example that you can use to get abbreviated time zone name:

```js
var startDate = new Date();
var momObj = moment.tz(startDate, moment.tz.guess());
var zoneAbbr1 = momObj.zoneAbbr();
console.log(zoneAbbr1);
var zoneAbbr2 = momObj.format('z')
console.log(zoneAbbr2);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.5/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For me it simply return UTC

Comment: Does my code snippet print UTC for you? What is the result of `moment.tz.guess()`? Are you executing code in the same environment of your question? Maybe you can show the code you used to create the moment object displayed in the screenshot

Comment: I simply have a date field coming from API.I just converted to Monet using moment(myDate).The result is what you saw in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed **moment-timezone** with

```
npm install moment-timezone --save
```

After that

```
var moment1 = require('moment-timezone');
var myTime = moment1.tz('America/Denver').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(myTime);
```